# How to dynamically change textview upon recieving API response?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

The buttonOnClick listener sets the result of the API to a text view, however, this result should change and show a different joke each time the button is clicked. Do i need to store the data from api into a list? Not sure how it would work.

Thanks :)

Main Activity Class

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RetroFitHelper service;
    private String calls;
    private Button btnJoke;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.chucknorris.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(RetroFitHelper.class);
          getJokes();
    }

    private  void getJokes(){
        Call<Joke> call = service.findJoke("religion");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Joke>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Joke> call, Response<Joke> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String result = response.body().getValue().getJoke();
                    btnJoke = findViewById(R.id.btnJoke);
                    TextView joke = findViewById(R.id.textView);

                    btnJoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            joke.setText(result);
                        }
                    });


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Joke> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Error 404 no response found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Joke and Value class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Joke {
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Value value;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

class Value {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("joke")
    @Expose
    private String joke;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> categories = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJoke() {
        return joke;
    }

    public void setJoke(String joke) {
        this.joke = joke;
    }

    public List<Object> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Object> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }}
```

Interface class

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

interface RetroFitHelper {


    @GET("/jokes/random/category=religion")
    Call<Joke> findJoke(@Path("category") String random);
}
```

Comment: For issue 2, you should not have to store them in a list, it should update each time.

Comment: @DJ_Polly is my button onClick code correct? Because when I click the button, it still shows me the same joke and doesn't change :/

Answer (score 0):

For issue 1, the problem is in your RetroFitHelper -

> ```
>  @GET("/jokes/random/category=religion")
> Call<Joke> findJoke(@Path("category") String random);
> ```

the `@Path("category")` annotation means you should have a variable called `{category}` in the String in the @GET value, e.g.

```
@GET("jokes/random/category={category}")
Call<Joke> findJoke(@Path("category") String random);
```

This means that whatever String is passed in as the `random` parameter, will replace `{category}` in the Get path when the call is made to the service.

Comment: thanks for that. I tried it but still doesn't work for some reason. No error in logcat but the joke doesnt show up on button click.

Comment: Yes, this was only an answer for the first issue, sorry :)